# Generic caching in c#

Tags: c#, generics, caching

Is there a more efficient way to check if cached data exits, if it does get it and if it doesn't make a call to the api/database and then cache it? It seems really inefficient for me to do code like this over and over.

```
List<Map> maps = new List<Map>();
List<Playlist> playlists = new List<Playlist>();

if (SingletonCacheManager.Instance.Get<List<Map>>("Maps") != null)
{
    maps = SingletonCacheManager.Instance.Get<ListMap>>("Maps");
}
else
{
    maps = _mapRepository.FindBy(x => x.Active).ToList();
    SingletonCacheManager.Instance.Add<List<Map>>(maps, "Maps", 20);
}

if (SingletonCacheManager.Instance.Get<List<Playlist>>("Playlists") != null)
{
    playlists = SingletonCacheManager.Instance.Get<List<Playlist>>("Playlists");
}
else
{
    var p = await _apiService.GetPlaylists();
    playlists = p.ToList();
    SingletonCacheManager.Instance.Add<List<Playlist>>(playlists, "Playlists", 20);
}
```

Is something like this possible:

```
List<Map> maps = this.CacheHelper.GetCachedItems<Map>(key, lengthoftime);
```

and then the GetCachedItems would do the check for the cached items and retrieve accordingly. This seems do able, but its when the cached items dont exist and I have to retrieve the items from the api/database that I dont know if its possible to make generic.

The only solution is a switch statement on the type passed in?

```
switch(<T>type)
{
  case<Map>:
      return _mapRepository.FindBy(x => x.Active);
  case<Playlist>:
      return await _apiService.GetPlaylists();
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I do something like this: https://github.com/WiredUK/Wired.Caching/blob/master/Wired.Caching/InMemoryCache.cs#L52. So essentially I'm passing in the function to get the data (from database, API or whatever) into the cache function and that only gets called if required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution to this is to pass in the function that gets the data you require cached as a lambda expression. That way, the cache method can check the cache and the call the delegate only when required. For example:

```
public T Get<T>(string key, Func<T> getItemDelegate, int duration) where T : class
{
    var cache = GetCache();

    var item = SingletonCacheManager.Instance.Get<ListMap>>(key) as T;

    if (item != null) return item;

    item = getItemDelegate();

    SingletonCacheManager.Instance.Add<T>(item, key, duration);

    return item;
}
```

Now you can call the Get function generically like this:

```
var maps = Get<List<Map>>(
    "Maps",
    () => _mapRepository.FindBy(x => x.Active).ToList(),
    20);
```

Comment: This is a cool answer! Ill try and implement when i get home.

Comment: You should probably also add a `lock` around this code too. Preferably based around the key, but you could lock on a general object though that may hit your performance.

Comment: Didnt realise you made the comment in the OP to. I think this is exactly what I am looking for! Thank you for this.

Comment: This does have the problem that *every* time you attempt to fetch cached data you have to pass in the appropiate lambda even if its not needed. This can lead to serious code repetition which can become an issue. Of course this is solvable accepting an additional argument in the lambda and in the call itself (and the necessary generic type argument). This way you can cache the lambda in a readonly variable  without worrying about dependency lifetimes as you well pointed out.

Comment: This is so great and just the thing that someone would need if they want a generic caching layer instead of the one that is repeating itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
public interface ICacheManager
{
    IList<T> Get<T>(string name);
    void Add<T>(IList<T> data, string Id, int lifeTime);
}

public class CacheHelper
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string>, Func<IEnumerable<object>>> dataRetrievalFuncs;
    private readonly ICacheManager cacheManager;

    public CacheHelper(ICacheManager cacheManager)
    {
        this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
        dataRetrievalFuncs = new Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string>, Func<IEnumerable<object>>>();
    }

    public void Register<T>(string name, Func<IEnumerable<T>> selector) where T : class
    {
        dataRetrievalFuncs[new Tuple<Type, string>(typeof(T), name)] = 
            () => (IEnumerable<object>)selector();
    }

    public IList<T> GetCachedItems<T>(string name, int lifeTime = 20)
        where T : class
    {
        var data = cacheManager?.Get<T>(name);

        if (data == null)
        {
            data = (dataRetrievalFuncs[new Tuple<Type, string>(
                       typeof(T), name)]() as IEnumerable<T>)
                   .ToList();
            cacheManager.Add(data, name, lifeTime);
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

And now, you'd need to register your data retrieval functions for each type and then simply use the helper:

```
//Setting up the helper
CacheHelper helper = new CacheHelper(SingletonCacheManager.Instance);
helper.Register("Maps", () => _mapRepository.FindBy(x => x.Active));
helper.Register( "PlayLists", ... );

//Retrieving data (where it comes from is not your concern)
helper.GetCachedItems<Map>("Maps");
helper.GetCachedItems<PlayList>("Playlists");
```

As pointed out in comments below, this solution can have a problem with the lifespan of dependencies (`_mapRepository`) used to retrieve data. A workaround would be to use this same solution but explicitly passing in the dependecies at the moment of data retrieval:

```
public class CacheHelper
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string>, Func<object, IEnumerable<object>>> dataRetrievalFuncs;
    private readonly ICacheManager cacheManager;

    public CacheHelper(ICacheManager cacheManager)
    {
        this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
        dataRetrievalFuncs = new Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string>, Func<object, IEnumerable<object>>>();
    }

    public void Register<TEntity, TProvider>(string name, Func<TProvider, IEnumerable<TEntity>> selector)
        where TEntity : class
        where TProvider: class
    {
        dataRetrievalFuncs[new Tuple<Type, string>(typeof(TEntity), name)] =
            provider => (IEnumerable<object>)selector((TProvider)provider)
    }

    public IList<TEntity> GetCachedItems<TEntity>(string name, object provider, int lifeTime = 20)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        var data = cacheManager?.Get<TEntity>(name);

        if (data == null)
        {
            data = (dataRetrievalFuncs[new Tuple<Type, string>( 
                       typeof(TEntity), name)](provider) as IEnumerable<TEntity>)
                   .ToList();
            cacheManager?.Add(data, name, lifeTime);
        }

        return data;
    }

}
```

Now the use would be slightly different:

```
//Setting up the helper
CacheHelper helper = new CacheHelper(SingletonCacheManager.Instance);
helper.Register("Maps", (MapRepository r) => r.FindBy(x => x.Active));

//Retrieving data (where it comes from is not your concern)
helper.GetCachedItems<Map>("Maps", _mapRepository);
```

Do note that this last solution is not type safe. You can pass in a wrongly typed `provider` to `GetCachedItems<T>` which is unfortunate.

Comment: This will break if you have two caches with the same type. Using OPs example, he's getting active maps as `List<Map`. what if they wanted inactive maps cached too?

Comment: @DavidG True, but that is easily solvable; a `Tuple<Type, string>` could be used as the key to the dictionary instead of only `Type`. I'll add that to the answer, its a good point.

Comment: Indeed. Of course another issue with this is that dependencies required for the functions may no longer exist. For example a db context may have been closed/disposed.

Comment: @DavidG Well yes, of course, I don't have to full context to know the lifespan of those objects. In your case you have to pass in the lambda *every* time you try to retrieve data, which means that you might have to copy and paste the same code 10 times with the problems that entails (the lambda might not be a one liner). This approach tries to avoid that, but it might not be possible.

Comment: Actually, it's not duplicate code at all. It's just a wrapper around functions that already exist in your code. Also, this way there is no way to manage external dependencies. For example, a service or db context was inject into your code.

Comment: @DavidG I'm not following you. In your solution, every time you need to call `Get<T>` you have to pass in a new lambda. The only way to avoid that is to store the lamda in a variable, but that brings up the problem you pointed out concerning the lifetime of the dependencies. This is solvable making the lambda accept the dependencies as arguments. See edits to my answer and the second proposed approach.

Comment: Im only getting round to implementing this now. It works great for caching database calls. What would I need to amended to make it work for API calls as they require an await operator.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use different caches for maps and playlists? If you do so, you can write one base abstract class and overide only the method that read data from api in each of them.

Comment: Interesting idea, might give this a go and see how it feels

Comment: Your idea with switch will not work, because you can not use type there.

Comment: Yeah it was just something that was off the top of my head.